# Trouble with Stripe Integration using Javascript and Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, stripe-payments, webflow

I have a form in a Webflow website that dynamically calculates a price depending on selectors the user has chosen.

```
`<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const selections = document.querySelectorAll('#language, input[name="turnaround"], #timecoding, input[name="textFormat"], input[name="speakers"]');
    const estimatedPriceElement = document.getElementById('estimatedPrice');
    const form = document.querySelector('form'); // Adjust selector as needed
    let fileSizeInMB = 0; // Initialize file size in MB, will be set by Uploadcare

    // Default multipliers for selections
    let defaultMultipliers = {
        language: 1, // Default multiplier for language
        turnaround: 1, // Default multiplier for turnaround time
        timecoding: 1, // Default multiplier for timecoding
        textFormat: 1, // Default multiplier for text format
        speakers: 1, // Default multiplier for speakers
    };

    function calculatePrice() {
        let priceMultiplier = 1; // Start with a multiplier of 1

        selections.forEach(selection => {
            if ((selection.type === 'radio' && selection.checked) || selection.type === 'select-one') {
                let selectionValue = parseFloat(selection.value);
                if (!isNaN(selectionValue)) {
                    priceMultiplier *= selectionValue;
                } else {
                    priceMultiplier *= defaultMultipliers[selection.name] || 1;
                }
            }
        });

        let finalPrice = fileSizeInMB * priceMultiplier;
        estimatedPriceElement.textContent = `$${isNaN(finalPrice) ? "N/A" : finalPrice.toFixed(2)}`;
    }

    selections.forEach(selection => {
        selection.addEventListener('change', calculatePrice);
    });

    const widget = uploadcare.Widget('#uploadcareWidget');
    widget.onUploadComplete(info => {
        fileSizeInMB = info.size / (1024 * 1024);
        calculatePrice();
    });

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default submission
        console.log("Form submit event triggered");
        // Capture the project name from the form
        const projectName = document.getElementById('project-name-2').value;
        const priceText = estimatedPriceElement.textContent;
        const price = parseInt(priceText.replace(/^\$/, '').replace(/,/g, '')) * 100; // Convert to cents
      
       console.log("Calculated price (in cents):", price);

    console.log("About to send fetch request", { price: price });
        fetch('https://test-app-123456-efc60cbf5fa3.herokuapp.com/create-checkout-session', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ price: price, name: projectName }) // Include the project name here
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Ensure we're accessing the 'url' property correctly
            if(data.url) {
                window.location.href = data.url; // Redirect to the Stripe checkout page
            } else {
                console.error('Session URL is undefined:', data);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
            });
        });
</script>`
```

Which is supposed to send a POST request to the server to create "create-checkout-session":

```
require 'stripe'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cors'

set :allow_origin, "****"
set :allow_methods, "GET,POST"
set :allow_headers, "content-type,if-modified-since"
set :expose_headers, "location,link"
set :cors_allow_credentials, true  # If your requests are made with credentials

# This is your test secret API key.
Stripe.api_key = '****'
set :static, true
set :port, ENV['PORT'] || ****

YOUR_DOMAIN = '****'
YOUR_SUCCESS_URL = YOUR_DOMAIN + '/success.html'
YOUR_CANCEL_URL = YOUR_DOMAIN + '/cancel.html'

get '/' do
  'Hello, world!'
end

post '/create-checkout-session' do
  content_type :json
  request_body = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

  puts "Endpoint /create-checkout-session hit"
  
  # Extract the project name from the request
  project_name = request_body['name']

  # Log received price for debugging

  final_price = request_body['price'].to_i

  if final_price <= 0
    status 400 # Bad Request
    return { error: 'Invalid price calculated.' }.to_json
  end
  
  # Create Stripe Checkout session with the final price
  begin
    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: project_name || 'Custom Product', # Use the project name or a default
          },
          unit_amount: final_price,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: YOUR_SUCCESS_URL,
      cancel_url: YOUR_CANCEL_URL,
    })

    { url: session.url }.to_json
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 500
    { error: e.message }.to_json
  end
end
```

The problem is the dynamically generated price doesn't show up in the Stripe Checkout page. The page is successfully created, but without the dynamic price.

I've tried adding a "puts" statement to show up in the console logs to check that it's successfully gone through, but it never appears. I also tried to simple change the product name rather than the price dynamically but that didn't work either.

Comment: What do you see on the checkout page instead?

Comment: The amount is $1.00 and the product is set to 'Custom Product'.

Comment: Can you log the received price on the backend?